# Convert C# 6.0 default propertyvalues to C# 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, properties, c#-6.0

```
public List<string> MembershipIds
{
    get;
    set;
} = new List<string>();
```

I got Invalid token

> "=" in class, struct or interface member declaration.

This is C# 6 feature. How to convert it to C# 5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it while leaving the auto-property in place.

If you do not require an auto property, convert the code to using a private variable and a non-automatic property:

```
private List<string> membershipIds = new List<string>();
public List<string> MembershipIds {
    get { return membershipIds; }
    set { membershipIds = value; }
}
```

If you do require the auto-property, you need to make the assignment in the constructor:

```
public List<string> MembershipIds { get;set; }
...
// This constructor will do the assignment.
// If you do not plan to publish no-argument constructor,
// it's OK to make it private.
public MyClass() {
    MembershipIds = new List<string>();
}
// All other constructors will call the no-arg constructor
public MyClass(int arg) : this() {// Call the no-arg constructor
    .. // do other things
}
public MyClass(string arg) : this() {// Call the no-arg constructor
    .. // do other things
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but when does one "require an auto-property"?

Comment: The chainings of `this()` need a syntactical correction.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, I switched to Java mode this morning! I think that the only case when one would require an auto-property is when there is a firm-wide coding standard requiring their use. I can't think of a technical reason to require their use over a variable+get/set pair.

Comment: @MrLore The difference Jeppe is asking about is not between properties and fields, but between regular properties and auto properties. NHibernate wouldn't be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is called *Default values for properties* and what it does is inserting the *assignment* part to the *constructors* of your `class`.

Changing the code to the following does the same on the backing field of that property without the need of changing all of your constructors, and it is supported on C# 5.0:

```
private List<string> mMembershipIds = new List<string>();

public List<string> MembershipIds
{
    get
    {
        return mMembershipIds;
    }
    set
    {
        mMembershipIds = value;
    }
}
```